# Using PySpark instead of the multiprocessing module - How can I translate my code?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, rdd

I am currently using the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module to parallelize iterations as shown in this example. The thing is that this way I would be using only 1 worker and its cores, but not using all the workers available. Also I'm not able to parallelize experiments (I'm running several experiments, and several iterations for each experiment).

This code is taking too long to run, and I have the understanding that the runtime could be highly reduced using PySpark. My Spark knowledge is very little and I don´t know how to translate this code in order to use it with Spark.
All the functions and classes used here are written using purely python, (numpy and pandas)

```py
import concurrent.futures

import multiprocessing as mp

def process_simulation(experiment):
  number_of_workers = mp.cpu_count()
  with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=number_of_workers) as executor:
      results = list(executor.map(Simulation.simulation_steps(), iterations_generator()))
      experiment.simulations = []
      for i, v in enumerate(results):
        experiment.simulations.append(results[v])
```

For context, Experiment and Simulation are classes (there's no inheritance). One experiment needs multiple simulations to be completed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fugue](https://fugue-tutorials.readthedocs.io/) to bring this type of logic to PySpark with a minimal wrapper. The only thing is you need to start with a DataFrame of inputs, and then you can do something like:

```
from fugue import transform

transform(input_df, Simulation.simulation_steps, schema=<your output schema here>, partition={"how": "per_row"}, engine="spark"
```

I can always help more get it in this shape if I have more details to what the logic is. It may just need one wrapper function. (contact info in bio).